# How can I reduce the amount of info Cruise Control.Net 1.8.3 is logging?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I just updated to CruiseControl.net 1.8.3 in hopes of resolving a problem with the Vault 6 interface (didnt help).

The problem I see now is that the log has become  "highly productive" - ie: it is producing much more info than ever before, usually messages I've never seen before. They are very detailed status messages for each project, displayed in green (meaning debug messages).

Setting levelMin to INFO has had no effect on these messages. Filtering has had no effect.

Any ideas on what I've missed?

Mark

Here is the log4net config from (rootCCNetFolder)\server\ccnet.exe.config:

```
<log4net>
    <level>
      <name value="INFO" />
      <value value="20000" />
    </level>
    <root>
      <!-- 
                Change the value in the next line to alter the amount of logging generated by CruiseControl.NET.
                The following values are supported: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, OFF.
                For more detailed information on how to configure log4net, see http://logging.apache.org/log4net/
                 -->
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender"/>
    </root>

    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <foreColor value="White"/>
        <backColor value="Red, HighIntensity"/>
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <foreColor value="Green"/>
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="WARN"/>
        <foreColor value="White"/>
        <backColor value="Blue, HighIntensity"/>
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <foreColor value="White"/>
      </mapping>

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%thread:%level] %message%newline"/>
      </layout>

      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
        <levelMin value="INFO" /> <!-- was DEBUG -->
        <levelMax value="ERROR" />
      </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="${TMP}\ccnet.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread:%level] %message%newline"/>
      </layout>

      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="ERROR" />
      </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>

      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="ERROR" />
      </filter>      
    </appender>


    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file value="${TMP}\ccnet.trace"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] [%level] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>

        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="ERROR" />
      </filter>   

    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Ended up needing to add explicit log4net filters to allow info/warn/debug and denyall after that to toss everything else.

Comment: I'd put your comment as an answer...and mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up needing to add explicit log4net filters to allow info/warn/debug and denyall after that to toss everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The problem is in these 2 lines:

```
<name value="INFO" />
<value value="20000" />
```

Here you're redefining what INFO means to log4net. Default value for INFO inside log4net source is 40000. And TRACE is, surprise, 20000.

So your INFO now means TRACE.